# Procrustes Analysis of 3d point cloud without defined landmarks

Tags: r, classification, rotation, procrustes-analysis

I am working with several hundred 3d point clouds generated using a 3d scanner and would like to be able to compare their shapes using something like a procrustes analysis. Instead of manually defining individual landmarks to compare however, I was hoping to compare the entire point cloud of each scan to all of the other scans to measure similarity of each point cloud to the rest of the dataset. Is this possible, and if so how would I go about it? I would like to use R if possible to do this analysis, though I do have access to other tools if need be.

Comment: Procrustes requires that points in the clouds are already matched, that is, any point _i_ in one cloud corresponds to point _i_ in another cloud. Is that your case? If not, you should somehow find such an optimal match prior procrustes, or choose another method instead of it.

Comment: No, the points are not matched, and scans can range from a few hundred thousand points to several million points per scan. Can you recommend any other methods that might be better suited for this?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot. But then it becomes not statistical but rather image comparison question. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/843972

Comment: Please, have a look at the following papers: http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVI/part5/paper/1243_Dresden06.pdf http://diglib.eg.org/EG/DL/PE/3DPVT/3DPVT2010Papers/27_paper036.pdf